# Pull one node of xml file using jquery ajax - include in html file

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have an xml file that displays an average wait time. I need to read that file, using jquery and ajax (or another technology if that's a better solution) and display it in an html page. I need to pull the data from the  node. I will also need to transform that data into a more reader friendly format. So 0:06 would display 6 minutes and 1:06 would display 1 hour and 6 minutes.

[You can see the xml file here.](http://www.citizensmemorial.com/Temp/edwaittimes.xml)

I've tried this code without success:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.citizensmemorial.com/Temp/edwaittimes.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('edWait').each(function(){
            var time = $(this).attr('AverageWait');

            $('+time+');

        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work? CORS? Reading XML? Formatting time?

Comment: I have my test page on the same domain, so it wouldn't be CORS correct? It's not returning any information. I haven't worked on the time formatting piece yet.

Comment: So what does it do? Where's the error? jQuery should be fine with an XML. `xml` would then be a Node. Not sure jQuery's good with that. Instead, try `console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName('edWait'))`. Anything?

Comment: Not sure how/where to try the console.log test. It doesn't return anything - no text  (other than the hardcoded word "test") and no error - http://www.citizensmemorial.com/Temp/edWaitTest.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is fetch `Patients` from the XML:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://www.citizensmemorial.com/Temp/edwaittimes.xml",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    // xml is the xml document
    // Find all `Patients`
    var patients = xml.querySelectorAll('patients');

    // Cycle through them to do stuff
    $.each(patients, function(i, node) {
      var time = node.querySelector('WaitTime').textContent.trim();
      time = convertTime(time);
      // Where do you want this time?
      // ...
    });
  }
});

function convertTime(time) {
  // I'm sure you can figure this out...
}
```

That should help.

Open your JS console, for god's sake. It'll tell you what works and what doesn't. F12 or CTRL+SHIFT+J. It'll tell you:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: +

Comment: Rudie, Thanks for the console tip. I removed the +, but I'm still not seeing any data. I'm very new to jquery/js. I only really need to pull the <AverageWait> which is not in the Patients node. I suppose I could pull all the waittimes and re-calculate the average wait, but that seems redundant.

Comment: `var avgTime = node.querySelector('AverageWait').textContent;` and then do something with it. I'm not writing your app. Maybe you should learn JS first.